# Invalid Pointer when freeing memory

Tags: c, gdb, free

I have a structure

```
typedef struct
{
    char **changeTime;  // Array of pointers
} r;
```

Size variables are as under

```
int SIZE = 10;
int BYTES = 1000;
```

Here I allocate memory

```
r.change_time = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * SIZE);
for(i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    r.changeTime[x] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * BYTES);
```

Lot of things happen

Finally I free memory

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
{
    if(r.changeTime[x] != NULL)
    {
        free(r.changeTime[x]);   <- Fails here
        r.changeTime[x] = NULL;  
    }
}
```

and finally

```
if(r.change_time != NULL)
{
    free(r.change_time)
    r.change_time = NULL;
}
```

Now, the code is failing at line mentioned above

I debugged using GDB. Here is the output

> ```
> > *** glibc detected *** XYZ: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000006b61021 ***
> > ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib64/libc.so.6[0x3e1b07247f] /lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4b)[0x3e1b0728db]
> > /panther/disk/libxc.so(free_record+0x1a)[0x2b303aadf44a]
> > /panther/disk/libxc.so(MW_free+0x33)[0x2b303aadf413]
> > /panther/disk/libxc.so(M1_free+0x1f)[0x2b303171a8cf]
> > /panther/disk/libxc.so(M_free+0x12)[0x2b3030f91122]
> > /panther/disk/libxc.so(term+0x34)[0x2b3027e4e294]
> > /panther/disk/libxc.so(proc+0x8c)[0x2b3027e5252c]
> > /panther/disk/libxc.so(main+0x5dd)[0x2b3027e3d79d]
> ```

**Please help !!**

Comment: That code you have is full of syntax errors. After cleaning up a bit, it compiled just fine on my PC

Comment: Perhaps you were modifying the `r` structure in some way inside that "Lots of things happen" part. Like replacing one or more of those mallocs with another string, and you end up trying to delete a string twice, or a string from some other stack

Comment: It is strange that you declared a constant called `SIZE`, properly used it in `malloc`,  and then completely ignored its existence when writing your `for` cycles. It is not an error yet, since the values match, but it can easily become one.

Comment: What is `x`??? And why are you using `x` instead of `i` inside the cycles?

Answer (score 2):

Your cycles use `i` as iterator variable. But your array access inside the cycle uses `x` as an index for some reason

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    r.changeTime[x] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * BYTES);
```

What on Earth is `x` and what is it doing there? You are lucky if `x` is in `[0, 10)` range.

And in any case, allocating memory 10 times and storing the pointer in the same `r.changeTime[x]` turns 9 of those 10 allocations into memory leaks.

Later you attempt to deallocate the same `r.changeTime[x]` ten times. If at that point `x` is out of range, then it expectedly triggers this error.

Answer (score 0):

> Please help

Run your program under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or [Address Sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/) ([also implemented in GCC](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/12/02/address-and-thread-sanitizers-gcc/)). Chances are, they'll point you straight at your bug.

> Lot of things happen

It's likely that the bug happens there.

Answer (score 0):

```
*** glibc detected *** XYZ: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000006b61021 ***
```

This line states that, the pointer you are trying to delete is not valid, the part of the code, where you are saying lot of things happen, you must have changed the value of `changeTime`, you would have made it point to something else, than the originally allocated memory.